# DS-160 : Personal Info Page 2 : Country dropdown doesn't has USA

Tags: visas

DS-160 : Personal Info Page 2 : Country dropdown doesn't has USA

did anyone had this issue earlier...i'm filling DS-160 for my kid who's US citizen and while filling personal info, the country dropdown doesn't has United states as option

Comment: Why does your child need a US visa if he or she is already a US citizen?

Comment: so, there's no need to fill DS-160 form for my kid (US Citizen) .... please confirm

Comment: @k2moo4 That makes sense. why do a citizen needs a visa ??/

Comment: Visas are only issued to people who are *not* citizens of that country, as citizens have a right to enter their own country (as a general rule).  If you child is outside the US and wants to enter the US, the correct procedure is to obtain a US passport.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to apply for a U.S. visa for someone who is already a U.S. citizen.

The correct way to ensure they have entry into the U.S. is to apply for a U.S. passport.